# How to Use Vapor Client to Route to Another Port

Tags: vapor

I want to use Vapor as the outside facing API to other internal services. For example:

```
drop.client.post("http://localhost:8091/someEndpoint")
```

However, I get an error explaining that the URL is not a URI (It has problems paling the port and the ":"). Furthermore, if I need to forward to multiple internal services, do I need multiple clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `0.0.0.0` instead.

```
drop.client.post("http://0.0.0.0:8091/someEndpoint")
```